# How do I check a condition within a loop java?

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, conditional-statements

First off I'm new to java and thought I would start by making some smaller programs to help myself learn. So I started a "Don't Step the White Tile" game and I got the printing of each line to print but I need to check whether the user input equals the tile. I'm not sure how to go about this because I've tried many things and I'm at a road block.

Anything help and thanks in advance.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DontStepTheWhiteTile {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Variables
        int userInput = 0, numberEntered = 0, tileNumber;
        char start;

        //Scanner
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Loop for tiles
        if (userInput == 0) {
            System.out.print("Enter the character 's' to begin: ");
            start = scanner.nextLine().charAt(0);
            if (start == 's') {
                userInput = 1;
            }
        }

        //Starts the time
        long timeStart = System.currentTimeMillis();

        //Makes the tiles
        if (userInput == 1){
            for (int i = 0; i <= 25; i++) {
                int tile = (int) (3 * Math.random() + 1);
                if (tile == 1){
                    System.out.print("1 | X | X = ");
                    numberEntered = scanner.nextInt();
                }
                else if (tile == 2){
                    System.out.print("X | 2 | X = ");
                    numberEntered = scanner.nextInt();
                }
                else {
                    System.out.print("X | X | 3 = ");
                    numberEntered = scanner.nextInt();
                }
            }
        }

        //Calculates the ending time
        long timeEnd = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("It took you " 
             + ((timeEnd - timeStart) / 1000) + " seconds");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never test `numberEntered` so the users input doesn't change the behavior of the code.  It would be easier to answer your question if you'd made clear what behavior you do want.  Since you don't I'm forced to guess.

If you want the game to end on the first miss a `break` out of the `for` loop will work.

```
if (numberEntered != tile) {
    System.out.println("You lose");
    break;
}
```

If you want the game to end on say 3 misses, an accumulating int that you test before the `break` will work.

```
if (numberEntered != tile) {
    misses++;
}
if (misses >= 3) {
    System.out.println("You lose");
    break;
}
```

Either way, all this code can go at the end of your `for` loop after your current `if-else` structure.

Infact `numberEntered = scanner.nextInt();` can be moved after the `if-else` as well since it's the same in every case.